# do_ovlp_io: WriteFileEx: The parameter is incorrect - Running SQLIO

Tags: cmd, performance-testing

http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/SAN_Performance_Tuning_with_SQLIO#Downloading_and_Configuring_SQLIO

Following along this SQLIO Video Tutorial and have run the batch file on all drives except the OS (Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise) drive. Now running on the C: drive and when I go to cmd and run "ArrayTest.bat > RESULTS-C.TXT" I get the following error:

do_ovlp_io: WriteFileEx: The parameter is incorrect.
file offset high: 0x00002b24 low: 0x5a550000
exiting

The same batch script ran fine on the other 4 disk arrays. Any idea what this error means?

The C: drive has 131GB free right now, so should be good there. However, it seems to create the data file and then throws an error when it gets to about 16GB in size.

My param.txt file has:
C:\Testfile.dat 2 0x0 20480

The ArrayTest.bat file has:

```
sqlio -kW -t2 -s120 -dC -o1 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t2 -s120 -dC -o2 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t2 -s120 -dC -o4 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t2 -s120 -dC -o8 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t2 -s120 -dC -o16 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t2 -s120 -dC -o32 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t2 -s120 -dC -o64 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t2 -s120 -dC -o128 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kW -t4 -s120 -dC -o1 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t4 -s120 -dC -o2 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t4 -s120 -dC -o4 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t4 -s120 -dC -o8 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t4 -s120 -dC -o16 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t4 -s120 -dC -o32 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t4 -s120 -dC -o64 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t4 -s120 -dC -o128 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -dC -o1 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -dC -o2 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -dC -o4 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -dC -o8 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -dC -o16 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -dC -o32 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -dC -o64 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -dC -o128 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kW -t16 -s120 -dC -o1 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t16 -s120 -dC -o2 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t16 -s120 -dC -o4 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t16 -s120 -dC -o8 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t16 -s120 -dC -o16 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t16 -s120 -dC -o32 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t16 -s120 -dC -o64 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t16 -s120 -dC -o128 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kW -t32 -s120 -dC -o1 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t32 -s120 -dC -o2 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t32 -s120 -dC -o4 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t32 -s120 -dC -o8 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t32 -s120 -dC -o16 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t32 -s120 -dC -o32 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t32 -s120 -dC -o64 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t32 -s120 -dC -o128 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kW -t64 -s120 -dC -o1 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t64 -s120 -dC -o2 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t64 -s120 -dC -o4 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t64 -s120 -dC -o8 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t64 -s120 -dC -o16 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t64 -s120 -dC -o32 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t64 -s120 -dC -o64 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t64 -s120 -dC -o128 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kR -t2 -s120 -dC -o1 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t2 -s120 -dC -o2 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t2 -s120 -dC -o4 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t2 -s120 -dC -o8 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t2 -s120 -dC -o16 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t2 -s120 -dC -o32 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t2 -s120 -dC -o64 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t2 -s120 -dC -o128 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kR -t4 -s120 -dC -o1 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t4 -s120 -dC -o2 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t4 -s120 -dC -o4 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t4 -s120 -dC -o8 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t4 -s120 -dC -o16 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t4 -s120 -dC -o32 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t4 -s120 -dC -o64 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t4 -s120 -dC -o128 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -dC -o1 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -dC -o2 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -dC -o4 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -dC -o8 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -dC -o16 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -dC -o32 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -dC -o64 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -dC -o128 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kR -t16 -s120 -dC -o1 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t16 -s120 -dC -o2 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t16 -s120 -dC -o4 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t16 -s120 -dC -o8 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t16 -s120 -dC -o16 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t16 -s120 -dC -o32 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t16 -s120 -dC -o64 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t16 -s120 -dC -o128 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kR -t32 -s120 -dC -o1 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t32 -s120 -dC -o2 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t32 -s120 -dC -o4 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t32 -s120 -dC -o8 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t32 -s120 -dC -o16 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t32 -s120 -dC -o32 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t32 -s120 -dC -o64 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t32 -s120 -dC -o128 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kR -t64 -s120 -dC -o1 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t64 -s120 -dC -o2 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t64 -s120 -dC -o4 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t64 -s120 -dC -o8 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t64 -s120 -dC -o16 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t64 -s120 -dC -o32 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t64 -s120 -dC -o64 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t64 -s120 -dC -o128 -frandom -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kW -t2 -s120 -dC -o1 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t2 -s120 -dC -o2 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t2 -s120 -dC -o4 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t2 -s120 -dC -o8 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t2 -s120 -dC -o16 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t2 -s120 -dC -o32 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t2 -s120 -dC -o64 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t2 -s120 -dC -o128 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kW -t4 -s120 -dC -o1 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t4 -s120 -dC -o2 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t4 -s120 -dC -o4 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t4 -s120 -dC -o8 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t4 -s120 -dC -o16 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t4 -s120 -dC -o32 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t4 -s120 -dC -o64 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t4 -s120 -dC -o128 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -dC -o1 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -dC -o2 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -dC -o4 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -dC -o8 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -dC -o16 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -dC -o32 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -dC -o64 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t8 -s120 -dC -o128 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kW -t16 -s120 -dC -o1 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t16 -s120 -dC -o2 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t16 -s120 -dC -o4 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t16 -s120 -dC -o8 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t16 -s120 -dC -o16 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t16 -s120 -dC -o32 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t16 -s120 -dC -o64 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t16 -s120 -dC -o128 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kW -t32 -s120 -dC -o1 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t32 -s120 -dC -o2 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t32 -s120 -dC -o4 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t32 -s120 -dC -o8 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t32 -s120 -dC -o16 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t32 -s120 -dC -o32 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t32 -s120 -dC -o64 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t32 -s120 -dC -o128 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kW -t64 -s120 -dC -o1 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t64 -s120 -dC -o2 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t64 -s120 -dC -o4 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t64 -s120 -dC -o8 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t64 -s120 -dC -o16 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t64 -s120 -dC -o32 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t64 -s120 -dC -o64 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kW -t64 -s120 -dC -o128 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kR -t2 -s120 -dC -o1 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t2 -s120 -dC -o2 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t2 -s120 -dC -o4 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t2 -s120 -dC -o8 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t2 -s120 -dC -o16 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t2 -s120 -dC -o32 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t2 -s120 -dC -o64 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t2 -s120 -dC -o128 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kR -t4 -s120 -dC -o1 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t4 -s120 -dC -o2 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t4 -s120 -dC -o4 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t4 -s120 -dC -o8 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t4 -s120 -dC -o16 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t4 -s120 -dC -o32 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t4 -s120 -dC -o64 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t4 -s120 -dC -o128 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -dC -o1 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -dC -o2 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -dC -o4 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -dC -o8 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -dC -o16 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -dC -o32 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -dC -o64 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t8 -s120 -dC -o128 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kR -t16 -s120 -dC -o1 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t16 -s120 -dC -o2 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t16 -s120 -dC -o4 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t16 -s120 -dC -o8 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t16 -s120 -dC -o16 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t16 -s120 -dC -o32 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t16 -s120 -dC -o64 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t16 -s120 -dC -o128 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kR -t32 -s120 -dC -o1 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t32 -s120 -dC -o2 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t32 -s120 -dC -o4 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t32 -s120 -dC -o8 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t32 -s120 -dC -o16 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t32 -s120 -dC -o32 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t32 -s120 -dC -o64 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t32 -s120 -dC -o128 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat

sqlio -kR -t64 -s120 -dC -o1 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t64 -s120 -dC -o2 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t64 -s120 -dC -o4 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t64 -s120 -dC -o8 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t64 -s120 -dC -o16 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t64 -s120 -dC -o32 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t64 -s120 -dC -o64 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
sqlio -kR -t64 -s120 -dC -o128 -fsequential -b64 -BH -LS Testfile.dat
```

The command I am running is ArrayTest.bat > RESULTS-C.TXT

Answer (score 0):

I followed the recommendation on the following post and it fixed the problem, good luck.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1263.sqlio-disk-subsystem-benchmark-tool-troubleshooting-hangs-and-errors.aspx

Comment: Please summarize the contents of the link; simply posting a link is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same issue. I've summarized the linked article:

> **Tips on how to prevent or resolve issues when running the SQLIO tool, especially on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2:**
>
> 1. Ensure that you have created an exception for SQLIO in Data Execution Prevention (DEP). In Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2,
>      you can create exceptions in DEP by opening System Properties
>      (sysdm.cpl) and then clicking Advanced. Then, in Performance, click
>      Settings. Click Data Execution Prevention. If Turn on DEP for all
>      programs and services except those I select is selected, click Add,
>      then type the full path to SQLIO.EXE, including SQLIO.EXE. For
>      example, C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLIO\SQLIO.EXE. If the other option,
>      Turn on DEP for essential Windows programs and services only is
>      selected, you do not need create an exception
> 2. If your SQLIO commands contain -fsequential and SQLIO is crashing, ensure you define a params.txt file that sets the test file size
>      before testing.
> 3. Ensure that all programs that are operating or could operate on the target drive for testing are off or suspended during the test. Two
>      common examples include: Ensure that you configure exceptions in any
>      virus scanning software that you have running or that could run during
>      your test for both SQLIO.EXE and the target volume of the test. Ensure
>      that you disable any drive indexing software.

Ref: [SQLIO Disk Subsystem Benchmark Tool: Troubleshooting Hangs and Errors](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1263.sqlio-disk-subsystem-benchmark-tool-troubleshooting-hangs-and-errors.aspx)